# Explain me like I'm 5 - RewriteRules, please

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I try to understand how to manage subdomains in Apache (mod_rewrite module).
On this website:
http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

This link below:

```
http://www.sub.tst.com/foo/bar.php
```

Under this rule:

```
RewriteRule (.*)bar(.*)$ $1oxo$2 [PT]
```

Returns:

```
✔ The new url is http://www.sub.tst.com/foo/oxo.php
```

But under following rule (or any other similar):

```
RewriteRule (.*)tst(.*)$ $1oxo$2 [PT]
```

It returns an error:

```
✖ This rule was not met.
```

I want to redirect links with subdomains to proper subfolders (to ***tst.com/sub/foo/bar*** link - if it exists), so I think I just have to cut ***www.sub.tst.com/foo/bar.php*** into 2 chunks, where 'sub' and '/foo/bar.php' I put after 'tst.com' (and remove '.php' extension from the end of it), but so far regex is not working on rewrite rules as I expect (and as I test it on php).
What is wrong? How to get it right? How to test it, before I use it on my website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search pattern uses standard regular expressions.  So in your case, the parenthesis constitutes a [regex group](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3513858/1911542). The first one matched will take the place of `$1`, and so on.  Remember also that regex are greedy. That is they will match as much as they can.

The reason your [`RewriteRule`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) doesn't match your example, is because the PATTERN is only checked against "[...] the part of the URL after the hostname and port".

To accomplish what you want, you might want to use a combination of [`RewriteCond`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) with `RewriteRule`.  So basically use `RewriteCond` to determine if a subdomain matches, then rewrite the domain part entirely.  Example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.sub.tst.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://tst.com/sub/$1 [L]
```

In this case, the `RewriteCond` works as an if statement for the following `RewriteRule`.

It's not pretty, but it might do the work for you.

---

**Updated**: based on comments from cooba and olaf.

You can accomplish what you need with the following rules

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.tst.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)*(([^.]*).)tst.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://tst.com/%3/$1 [L]
```

Start from the 2nd `RewriteCond`.  Here, the first part of of the regex `^(www.)` is needed to find cases where the domain contains www or not (www.sub.tst.com or sub.tst.com).

The second part of the regex `(([^.]*)\.)` matches the subdomain.  The part we want is the inside group (the one without the `.`).  When the regex is evaluated, that inner group takes position 3.  To access that value in the `RewriteRule`, you use `%`.

Now, the 1st `RewriteCond` is needed to guard about rewriting www.tst.com into tst.com/www/.

Comment: If I use the same pattern for http://sub.tst.com/foo/bar link - than "This condition is not met". There are so many cases and subfolders, so do I have to create always a separate rule for each one of them?

Comment: @cooba You can capture part of the domain, e.g. `www.(.+?).tst.com` and then use it in the substitution `http://tst.com/%1/$1`. Notice the percent `%` vs dollar `$` sign.

Comment: @OlafDietsche Your regex is still catching only one case: [https://regex101.com/r/xZ6uK1/1](https://regex101.com/r/xZ6uK1/1). Why you use single dot '.' instead of '\.'? Do you know any other place where I could ask about RewriteRules?

Comment: @cooba Most of your samples are irrelevant, because `HTTP_HOST` is just the domain part, nothing else. It doesn't include `http`, `/`, or any other part of the request. To learn about mod_rewrite, you can just follow jzer7's link. But in this case, it's more about the regular expression.

Comment: Using `.` instead of `\.` was just laziness.

Comment: Thank you @olafDietsche, that tip about `%1` was great.

Comment: @jzer7 On my website last rules are creating deeper cascading loop (from: /foo/bar.php - towards: /foo/foo/foo/bar.php...) and it's opening index.php file - instead of bar.php file. What could be wrong? Is there any non site-affecting way to test htaccess file custom modifications?